# Send database-name by $_POST-value not work

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem. It takes now about 5 hours, and i didn't solve it.

If I set the $dbName="dbTest" direct in the php-file, it works. (See comments in the code).

If I pass my database-name by $dbName = $_POST["dbName"] I get following Error: 
"Ther was an error running the query [No database selected]"

I cannot belief this! Please help.

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['dbName'])) {
        $dbName = $_POST["dbName"];

        function db_connection($query) 
             global $dbName;

                echo $dbName //dbTest
                echo strcmp ($dbName,'dbTest') //always 0 (equal)
                // $dbName ='dbTest' // if I comment this out, it works!
                $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', $dbName);

                if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
                   die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
                } 

                if (!$result = $db->query($query)) {
                    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
                }
             }
    }
?>
```

Comment: why would you pass database name in $_POST..!

Comment: You have a few missing ending semi-colons; IF that's your working code, add them.

Comment: Place your `$dbName = $_POST["dbName"];` into the `db_connection ` function :)

Comment: also, where do you call that function?

Comment: echo $dbName before the connection function and check out whether you are getting the expected value???

Comment: Make sure your form element is named. I.e.: `<input type="text" name="dbName">` - NOTA: `dbName` is not the same as `dbname` when it comes to POST variables. Plus, you may want to add `trim()`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: I tried to put it in the db_connection function. 
As i wrote: It works fine, if i set $dbName = 'dbTest'; 
If i set it with **$dbName = $_POST["dbName"];** and use var_dump($dbName) => show type string(9) and dbTest. Exactly thesame as i set it direct. But it does not work...

Comment: If i echo $dbName anywhere it is alwas 'dbTest',
but if i ** $db = mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection) or die("Couldn't select database: " .$dbName );** suddenly it is empty!
_Real Magic!!!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `isset` to verify you are sending the value: http://php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php

```
<?php
     if (isset($_POST['dbName'])) {
        $dbName = $_POST["dbName"];

        function db_connection($query) 
             global $dbName;

                echo $dbName //dbTest
                echo strcmp ($dbName,'dbTest') //always 0 (equal)
                // $dbName ='dbTest' // if I comment this out, it works!
                $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', $dbName);

                if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
                   die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
                } 

                if (!$result = $db->query($query)) {
                    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
                }
             }
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I still don't understand... It feels like isset is waiting to receive the Post-Values. If i don't use the if(isset...){..} mysqli don't get the $dbName. ??????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: The initials comments in your post show that is not good to pass via `$_POST` the database name, better put it directly in the function where you make the database connection, this is for security :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$dbName = $_POST["dbName"];
$query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE'; // query example or if comes via [$_POST][1] $query = $_POST['query'];
$connection = db_connection($query, $dbName);

function db_connection($query $dbName) {
     global $dbName;


    echo $dbName //dbTest
    echo strcmp ($dbName,'dbTest') //always 0 (equal)
    // $dbName ='dbTest' // if I comment this out, it works!
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', $dbName);

    if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
       die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    } 

    if (!$result = $db->query($query)) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It already work, if i set **$dbName='dbTest'**. So there are no Erros with the query... Only when i set **$dbName = $_POST["dbName"]** it does not work. **echo $dbName** result _dbTest_, don't care how i set it. **var_dump($dbName)** return exactly return the same, don't care how i set it.
But One work, the other not :( :( :(

Comment: show where are you sending the `dbName` field?, that way i could help you :)

Comment: Copy my Code with isset at the top (i changed it) as a new answer, and i mark it as answered! Thx